# Microsoft Face API Grouping: FaceNotFound error

Tags: face-recognition, azure-cognitive-services

I can't seem to figure out how to get the Grouping API to work.

Using: POST https://api.projectoxford.ai/face/v0/groupings
With a post body: `{
  "faceIds":[ 
    "29b9ace3-d7a0-4857-b6d0-88b1dac52c94",
    "b1bb38de-4557-424b-9c05-7b4b76ab6206",
    "acd760c4-230b-4d5a-9850-d695ceb63caf",
    "1e53e861-4d7b-441f-8730-0b1b212cbf20",
    "b8bcedf4-3388-49fb-825d-f3b8259bb40b",
    "14838f46-d7c5-4e8f-b864-6c51d6608916"
    ]
  }`

The error returned is. `{
  "code": "FaceNotFound",
  "message": "Face '29b9ace3-d7a0-4857-b6d0-88b1dac52c94' is not found."
}`

The faceIds were generated shortly before, using the Detect Api, with the same subscription key. I used the console for testing:
https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/54d85c1d5eefd00dc474a0ef/operations/551901793d8a4b22aca9157a/console

The same happens with the example faceIds in the console.
My original usecase was trying to run grouping on a persongroup by retrieving the persistedFaceIds and then sending them for grouping, but the same error occurs.

Am I doing something wrong?
Can anyone who uses this feature confirm that it actually works?

Appreciate the help.

Thanks,
Marton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out:

- faceIds generated with Detect using v0 of the API are not recognized
  by v1 of the API
- persistedFaceIds are not supported in Grouping

Comment: Was the version difference for me. v0 has now been discontinued.